# Default Plugin Settings Not Writing to Database

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database, options, activation

I have my plugin setup as such:

Main plugin file `mouldings.php`

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Moulding Profiles
Plugin URI: 
Description: Creates a 'Moulding Profiles' and 'Idea Gallery' custom post type, creates a 'Wood Types' and 'Categories' taxonomy for 'Moulding Profiles'
Version: 0.1
Author: 
Author URI: 
License: GPL2
*/

// Global Variables
$mouldings_prefix = 'mouldings_';
$mouldings_name = 'Mouldings';


// plugin folder url
if(!defined('MOULDINGS_BASE_URL')) {
    define('MOULDINGS_BASE_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));
}
// plugin folder path
if(!defined('MOULDINGS_BASE_DIR')) {
    define('MOULDINGS_BASE_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ));
}
// plugin root file
if(!defined('MOULDINGS_PLUGIN_FILE')) {
    define('MOULDINGS_PLUGIN_FILE', __FILE__);
}

// Includes
include('includes/register-settings.php'); // Register

// Retrieve settings from the options page
$mouldings_options = get_option('mouldings_settings');

include('includes/install.php'); // Sets default plugin settings on activation
include('includes/plugin-settings.php'); // Plugin options page HTML/Save functions
include('includes/scripts.php'); // Conrols JS/CSS
include('includes/admin-post-types.php'); // Sets up post types/taxonomies
include('includes/helper-functions.php'); // Functions that extend functionality of Mouldings
include('includes/admin-metaboxes.php'); // Metaboxes that appear in the admin (non-ACF)
include('includes/display-functions.php'); // Holds filters/actions for output

?>
```

In `register_settings.php` I have setup the options:

```
<?php

function mouldings_register_settings_initial() {

    if( false == get_option( 'mouldings_settings' ) ) {  
        add_option( 'mouldings_settings' );  
    }

    register_setting('mouldings_settings_group', 'idea_gallery_thumb_height');
    register_setting('mouldings_settings_group', 'idea_gallery_thumb_width');
    register_setting('mouldings_settings_group', 'collection_thumb_height');
    register_setting('mouldings_settings_group', 'collection_thumb_width');
    register_setting('mouldings_settings_group', 'profile_item_columns');
    register_setting('mouldings_settings_group', 'idea_item_columns');
    register_setting('mouldings_settings_group', 'collections_item_columns');
    register_setting('mouldings_settings_group', 'combinations_item_columns');

}
add_action('admin_init', 'mouldings_register_settings_initial');
```

and then in `install.php`

```
<?php

function mouldings_activate() {
    global $wpdb, $mouldings_options;
    if ($mouldings_options === false){
        $mouldings_options = array(
            'idea_item_columns' => '4'
        );
        update_option( 'mouldings_settings', $mouldings_options );
    }
}
register_activation_hook( MOULDINGS_PLUGIN_FILE, 'mouldings_activate' );
```

So, what I'm trying to do is setup the options table entry, `moulding_settings`, register the settings and then on activation, set the test value, `idea_item_colummns` to `4`. On activation currently, the options table entry is created, but without any settings and the default `idea_item_columns` is not set/created either. Once I visit my settings page and save the values, they pop-up in that table as need - but something just doesn't seem to be clicking on activation. Here is my settings page if that helps at all:

```
<?php

function mouldings_options_page() {

    global $mouldings_options;

    ob_start(); ?>

    <div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php _e('Mouldings Options','roots'); ?></h2>

        <form method="post" action="options.php" id="mouldings_options">

            <?php settings_fields('mouldings_settings_group'); ?>

            <h4><?php _e('Image Sizes','roots'); ?></h4>
            <p class="description"><?php _e('The options below are used to resize the various images that appear throughout Moulding Profiles, Idea Galleries, Moulding Combinations and Moulding Collections. If any values are left blank, they are assumed to be un-restricted. If you put anything other than a number in those boxes, I\'ll take out the screws in your office chair.','roots'); ?></p>

            <p>
                <label class="description" for="mouldings_settings[idea_gallery_thumb_height]"><?php _e('Idea Gallery Thumbnail Size','roots'); ?></label>
                <input id="mouldings_settings[idea_gallery_thumb_height]" name="mouldings_settings[idea_gallery_thumb_height]" type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($mouldings_options['idea_gallery_thumb_height'])) ? $mouldings_options['idea_gallery_thumb_height'] : ''; ?>">
                <span class="description"><?php _e('height (pixels)','roots'); ?></span>
                <input id="mouldings_settings[idea_gallery_thumb_width]" name="mouldings_settings[idea_gallery_thumb_width]" type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($mouldings_options['idea_gallery_thumb_width'])) ? $mouldings_options['idea_gallery_thumb_width'] : ''; ?>">
                <span class="description"><?php _e('width (pixels)','roots'); ?></span>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label class="description" for="mouldings_settings[collection_thumb_height]"><?php _e('Moulding Collection Thumbnail Size','roots'); ?></label>
                <input id="mouldings_settings[collection_thumb_height]" name="mouldings_settings[collection_thumb_height]" type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($mouldings_options['collection_thumb_height'])) ? $mouldings_options['collection_thumb_height'] : ''; ?>">
                <span class="description"><?php _e('height (pixels)','roots'); ?></span>
                <input id="mouldings_settings[collection_thumb_width]" name="mouldings_settings[collection_thumb_width]" type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($mouldings_options['collection_thumb_width'])) ? $mouldings_options['collection_thumb_width'] : ''; ?>">
                <span class="description"><?php _e('width (pixels)','roots'); ?></span>
            </p>

            <h4><?php _e('Column Settings','roots'); ?></h4>
            <p class="description"><?php _e('The options below are used to set a column count for each row.','roots'); ?></p>
            <?php $item_columns = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'); ?>

            <p>
                <label class="description" for="mouldings_settings[profile_item_columns]"><?php _e('Moulding Profile Item Columns','roots'); ?></label>
                <?php $profile_item_columns = $item_columns ?>
                <select name="mouldings_settings[profile_item_columns]" id="mouldings_settings[profile_item_columns]">
                    <?php foreach($profile_item_columns as $profile_item_column) { ?>
                    <?php if($mouldings_options['profile_item_columns'] == $profile_item_column) { $selected = 'selected="selected"'; } else { $selected = ''; } ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $profile_item_column; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $profile_item_column; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label class="description" for="mouldings_settings[idea_item_columns]"><?php _e('Idea Gallery Item Columns','roots'); ?></label>
                <?php $idea_item_columns = $item_columns ?>
                <select name="mouldings_settings[idea_item_columns]" id="mouldings_settings[idea_item_columns]">
                    <?php foreach($idea_item_columns as $idea_item_column) { ?>
                    <?php if($mouldings_options['idea_item_columns'] == $idea_item_column) { $selected = 'selected="selected"'; } else { $selected = ''; } ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $idea_item_column; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $idea_item_column; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label class="description" for="mouldings_settings[collections_item_columns]"><?php _e('Moulding Collections Item Columns','roots'); ?></label>
                <?php $collections_item_columns = $item_columns ?>
                <select name="mouldings_settings[collections_item_columns]" id="mouldings_settings[collections_item_columns]">
                    <?php foreach($collections_item_columns as $collections_item_column) { ?>
                    <?php if($mouldings_options['collections_item_columns'] == $collections_item_column) { $selected = 'selected="selected"'; } else { $selected = ''; } ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $collections_item_column; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $collections_item_column; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label class="description" for="mouldings_settings[combinations_item_columns]"><?php _e('Moulding Combinations Item Columns','roots'); ?></label>
                <?php $combinations_item_columns = $item_columns ?>
                <select name="mouldings_settings[combinations_item_columns]" id="mouldings_settings[combinations_item_columns]">
                    <?php foreach($combinations_item_columns as $combinations_item_column) { ?>
                    <?php if($mouldings_options['combinations_item_columns'] == $combinations_item_column) { $selected = 'selected="selected"'; } else { $selected = ''; } ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $combinations_item_column; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $combinations_item_column; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </p>


            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Options','roots'); ?>">
            </p>

            <?php

            if(function_exists('RegenerateThumbnails')) {
                ob_start(); ?>

                <div class="updated"> 
                    <p><strong>Notice:</strong> If you are altering the thumbnail sizes, remember to <a href="<?php echo admin_url('tools.php?page=regenerate-thumbnails'); ?>">Regenerate Thumbnails</a></p>
                </div>
                <?php echo ob_get_clean();
            }
            else {
                ob_start(); ?>

                <div class="error"> 
                    <p><strong>Notice:</strong> You do not have <a href="<?php echo admin_url('plugin-install.php?tab=search&type=term&s=regenerate+thumbnails&plugin-search-input=Search+Plugins'); ?>">Regenerate Thumbnails</a> installed. It is recommended to use this plugin - as this is the tool used to re-sample your images based on your preferences.</p>
                </div>
                <?php echo ob_get_clean();
            }

            ?>

        </form>

    </div>

    <?php
    echo ob_get_clean();
}

function mouldings_add_options_link() {
    add_options_page(__('Mouldings Options','roots'),__('Mouldings','roots'),'manage_options','mouldings-options','mouldings_options_page');
}
add_action('admin_menu','mouldings_add_options_link');

function mouldings_register_settings() {
    register_setting('mouldings_settings_group','mouldings_settings');
}
add_action('admin_init','mouldings_register_settings');

?>
```

I've been at this for a few hours and am hoping it's something small (well, if it's too small, I may loose my sanity, but any help would really be appreciated). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is that your function that sets up the settings initially isn't getting run upon activation. Add a call to your mouldings_register_settings_initial() in the activation hook, like this:

```
function mouldings_activate() {
    global $wpdb, $mouldings_options;
    mouldings_register_settings_initial();
    if ($mouldings_options === false){
        $mouldings_options = array(
            'idea_item_columns' => '4'
        );
        update_option( 'mouldings_settings', $mouldings_options );
    }
}
register_activation_hook( MOULDINGS_PLUGIN_FILE, 'mouldings_activate' );
```

Comment: Hey @pippin really appreciate the answer, but sadly, no dice. The `register_setting` should be set to the settings group, `mouldings_settings_group` right (that is first called in `plugin-settings.php`)?

Comment: Just realized what it is. Your mouldings_register_settings_initial() function is incorrect. register_setting() should only be called once, like this:
`function mouldings_register_settings_initial() {
    if( false == get_option( 'mouldings_settings' ) ) {  
        add_option( 'mouldings_settings' );  
    }
    register_setting('mouldings_settings_group', 'mouldings_settings');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'mouldings_register_settings_initial');`

Comment: Here is a pastebin that is easier to read: http://pastebin.com/gth5maSQ

Comment: Hey @pippin appreciate you hanging with me on this - that doesn't seem to be doing the trick either -- I also tried taking out that first snippet you suggested without any avail. Is it possibly "where" I am setting up those setting fields? I followed your "writing your first plugin" series which sets up the options a little differently than what I referenced in EDD - could that be it? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, one more issue. You are doing the register_setting() function twice. Once in mouldings_register_settings_initial() and once in mouldings_register_settings().

Also, which part isn't working? Do the settings save, just not get created on initial activation?

Comment: I removed the `register_settings()` from `register-settings.php` (so it still appears in `plugin-settings.php`

The options themselves save, but they are just not created on initial activation.

`mouldings.php` http://pastebin.com/zpXKHneC
`includes/plugin-settings.php` http://pastebin.com/3CLy5Act
`includes/register-settings.php` http://pastebin.com/p4TGE3Mk
`includes/install.php` http://pastebin.com/qgTikH3j

Comment: I'm wondering if this is something to do with where those `includes` are (as far as, should `plugin-settings.php` be set before `install.php`)? Thanks.

Comment: In mouldings_activate(), replace

 if ($mouldings_options === false){

with

if( false == get_option( 'mouldings_settings' ) ) {  

and then remove mouldings_register_settings_initial() completely.

Comment: Woohoo! You're awesome Pippin! Thank you very much

Comment: Yay! Just took a few tries to get it right ;)